# AngularJS waiting for a single asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework, q

I'm trying to put some data on the scope returned by an async call. 
I have an array in the factory called companies.

```
factory.getByCategoryId = function (id) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/campaign?access-token=12345&id=2').then(
    function (result) {
      factory.companies = [];
      if (result.data.length !== 0) {
        for (var index = 0; index < result.data.length; index++) {
          factory.companies.push(result.data[index]);
       }
      } else {
        console.log('Result is not set.', result);
      }
    },
    function (result) {
      console.log('Failed', result);
    }
  );
}
```

Calling the function:

```
$scope.closeModal = function (index) {
  if (index) {
    var promises = []

    promises.push(Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id));

    $q.all(promises).then(function () {
      $scope.myItems = Service.all(); //return all from factory.companies

      $scope.refreshItems(); //this function refreshes the DOM using myItems
    });
  }
}
```

Calling this function for the first time factory.companies staying the same it was but after the second call its updated. I'm sure somehow the app should wait more but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only return the `$http` from your Service

In your factory:

```
factory.getByCategoryId = function (id) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost/campaign?access-token=12345&id=2');
}
```

And your function

```
$scope.closeModal = function (index) {
    Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id).then(
    function (result) {
        if (result.data.length) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(value) {
                $scope.myItems.push(value);
            });
            $scope.refreshItems();
        } else {
            console.log('Result is not set.', result);
        }
    },
    function (result) {
      console.log('Failed', result);
    }
};
```

Or you could rewrite your service function to resolve a promise:

```
factory.getByCategoryId = function (id) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http.get('http://localhost/campaign?access-token=12345&id=2').then(
            function (result) {
                factory.companies = [];
                if (result.data.length !== 0) {
                    for (var index = 0; index < result.data.length; index++) {
                        factory.companies.push(result.data[index]);
                    }
                    resolve(factory.companies);
                } else {
                    reject('Result is not set.', result);
                }
            },
            function (result) {
                console.log('Failed', result);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

And use it as

```
$scope.closeModal = function (index) {
    Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id).then(function(result) {
    $scope.myItems = result;
    $scope.refreshItems();
}, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Köszönöm Alex, sokat segítettél! (:

Answer (score 1):

If

> Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id)

Is returning a promise then

```
$scope.closeModal = function (index) {
if (index) {
    Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id).then(function (res) {
        $scope.myItems = Service.all(); //return all from factory.companies
        $scope.refreshItems(); //this function refreshes the DOM using myItems
    }, function (res) {
        // Error Handling
    })
 }
}
```

> For Reference ::

```
app.factory('Service', function ($http) {
return {
    // Below function retuns a promsie
    getByCategoryId_promise: function () {
        // This simply sends the promise but you need to make it execute using $q 
        //or by entending like the closeModal method above
        return $http.get("URL GOES HERE");
    },
    // Below function retuns results from a promise
    getByCategoryId: function () {
        // This Function waits till the HTTP call is resolved and then sends the result
        return $http.get("URL GOES HERE").then(function (res) { }, function (res) { })
    },
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I gave you an UP but because of my low reputation its not showing yet.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     promises.push(Service.getByCategoryId($scope.categories[index].id));
> ```

So you take the return value of `Service.getByCategoryId` and `push` it into `promises`.

What is the return value of `Service.getByCategoryId`?

It doesn't have a `return` statement, so it is `undefined`.

You need to modify `Service.getByCategoryId` so it returns a promise (presumably the return value of `$http.get`).

Comment: Isn't it just about the time? I gave my service function a return value but I don't need it. I need only the refilled array from the factory. I have the same problem, it works only for the second call.